# Application crashes in NSOperationQueue concurrent threads by using NSURLSessionDataTask

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, nsoperationqueue, nsurlsession

My application getting crashes when downloading data from server using NSURLSessionDataTask in NSOperationQueue.
I am using the following code In NSOperation class.

```
- (void) main {
    @autoreleasepool {
        if (self.isCancelled)
            return;

        [self getGroupDetailsWithStream:_stream];
    }
}

- (void) getGroupDetailsWithStream : (CF_Stream*) stream {
    [[WebCommunication sharedInstances] getData:^(NSArray *responce, BOOL status) {
        if (status) {
            if ([[responce valueForKey:KEY_SUCCESS] integerValue] == 1) {
                if (status) {
                    _groupData = [[GroupData alloc] initWithResultSet:[responce valueForKey:KEY_GROUPPROFILE]];
                    [self setFinished:YES];
                    [(NSObject *)self.delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(groupDownloadDidFinish:) withObject:self waitUntilDone:NO];
                }
            }
        }
    } withUrl:urlString withAuthToken:authToken];
}

#pragma mark - NSOperation methods

- (BOOL)isConcurrent
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)setExecuting:(BOOL)executing
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    _isExecuting = executing;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
}

- (void)setFinished:(BOOL)finished
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    _isFinished = finished;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
}
```

And Below is the code for WebCommunication class.

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: nil];

    [self getHeaderMethodWithUrl:urlStr withAuthToken:authToken];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
    NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:mutablerequest
                                                       completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                                           [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
                                                           NSArray *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
                                                           if (!error && [result count] > 0) {
                                                               myCompletionBlock(result,YES);
                                                           } else {
                                                               myCompletionBlock(nil,NO);
                                                           }
                                                       }];
    [dataTask resume];
```

The Code for mutablerequest

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
    mutablerequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];
    [mutablerequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    if ([authToken length] >0) {
        [mutablerequest setValue:authToken forHTTPHeaderField:KEY_AUTHTOKEN];
    }
    [mutablerequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
```

I think app crashes while returning the block.

Error message -__NSCFType HTTPBodyStream  unrecognized selector

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the code you used to instantiate mutablerequest ?

Comment: Thanks for response. I have added the code for mutablerequest. Is anything wrong in the code?

Comment: I'm not being able to figure out just by looking at your code, but __NSCFType HTTPBodyStream unrecognized selector means that some object is trying to access a HTTPBodyStream method that doesn't exist

Comment: Have you tried using an [exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) to help you figure out where exactly the crash is happening?

Comment: Yes i have added exception breakpoint its crashing on         mutablerequest setValue:authToken forHTTPHeaderField:KEY_AUTHTOKEN